# Quickly Change Resource Resolutions

Tags: android, resolution, hdpi, mdpi

Are there any programs out there to upload a bunch of Android resources to and it will change the image's dimensions according to hdpi and mdpi?  I have about 50 different pictures all in hdpi resolution and it would take forever to re-size them all by hand...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use GIMP and its batch processing feature for resizing multiple files.
[GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/)
[Batch Process File using GIMP](http://www.maketecheasier.com/batch-process-files-in-gimp/2010/12/31)

Comment: Great! I will look into GIMP

Comment: +1 for GIMP. Though, bear in mind that simply scaling up/down a UI resources/icons looses detail, they won't look good on screen. They have to be pixel edited, simplifying/adding details and contrast.

Comment: Will the resources loose detail if I only scale them down?  I understand why they would loose detail scaling them up.

Answer (score 0):

Google provides an online service. Just upload the image, it will generate all the images with all folder & you can download it.

https://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html

Comment: This would work with single images only.  I have about 50 different pictures that need to be re-sized.